# Importing default and named imports from a file is not working?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have these exports in my .js file:

```
export const title = 'Message \n + one';
export const placeHolder = 'Message two';
export default data; //array
```

Then i import it in file where I want to use it:

```
import data, { placeHolder, title } from '../components/data/event-data';
```

But 'title' is underlined with message

```
title not found in '../components/data/event-data'(import/named)
```

Why? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure it's not a cache issue? From your export statements, both named exports `placeHolder` and `title` should be available :)

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import or similar? This looks like a linting error and the linter or a plugin might have a bug.

Comment: Thank you. Solved. Also cache also eslint rules.

Answer (score 1):

Cache and ESLint rules issues.